# Edit character requirement

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Can we get rid of the requirement that edits have to be at least six characters? Often a post is missing a letter or punctuation and that's all I want to change. I don't want to have to start editing an otherwise very well written post.

Answer (score 2):

Note that it's only [*suggested* edits](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251) that have this technical limit. And [once you've earned 2000 reputation points, you can edit without suggesting](/help/privileges/edit). Here's what [Jeff Atwood](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood) [had to say](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257) back in 2011:

> As a < 2k rep user, you should make reasonably substantive edits. The approval cost for your edit is not free, as it costs the attention of one or more users who have to look at your edit and think about it. This cost is high for extremely trivial edits.
>
> This will not be changing.
>
> ### If you want to make single-character trivial edits, earn 2k rep.

Comment: I don't know what suggested posts are. All I know is that whenever I try to fix a missing letter or the like it doesn't let me. I don't have 2000 reputation and I don't see why it should be necessary for me to add a missing letter or missing punctuation that will be perfect reviewed anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Suggested edits, not suggested posts. I've edited the answer to link to an explanation of suggested edits. Anyway, that it will be peer reviewed is the very problem, according to Mr. Atwood: by putting such a slight change before your peers, you're wasting their time.